# RuleFit Package

Tags: macos, r

I am using the RuleFit package in R and I create a rulefit model. However, when I run the function `rules()` I get the error message:

```
/bin/sh: xterm: command not found
```

I am not sure why I am getting this message. Other functions such as `varimp()` work fine.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Where do you use this command? Give us more information

Comment: I second Atilla. The [homepage](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~jhf/R-RuleFit.html) indicates that the installation is not as straightforward as for _standard_ R-packages. Do you use RuleFit or RuleFit3 ?

Comment: I am using  RuleFit3 for MAC OSX and I run the function in my R terminal. Other functions work fine but this function does not work.